# There was an error talking to Libvirt: Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: Unable to get index for interface eth0: No such device

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vagrant

My computer is Ubuntu Desktop 16.

I am using Vagrant and KVM libvirt to create virtual machines.

However, I want my machines to connect to the Wi-Fi of my home and have IP addresses of the Wi-Fi network.

When I mention the "public network" option in Vagrantfile, and I "vagrant up", I get the following error:

```
There was an error talking to Libvirt. The error message is shown
below:

Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: Unable to get index for interface eth0: No such device
```

And I have the following as my Vagrantfile code:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.network "public_network"

  config.vm.define "master" do |master|
    master.vm.hostname = "master"
    master.vm.box = "s3than/trusty64"
  end  

end
```

How can I fix the problem? Please I need the exact commands I am a very basic beginner in Linux. HELP ASAP!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [README.md example at the root of the repo](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt#networks), which worked for me

```
   config.vm.network :public_network,
      :dev => "virbr0",
      :mode => "bridge",
      :type => "bridge"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an eth0 in your interfaces, then as a workaround you can edit your wireless interface to be eth0 as it is hardcoded somewhere in the module to look for that name. You need to create /etc/udev/rules.d/70-rename-wireless.rules and insert the following into it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0
```

Where ATTR is the HWaddr field from ifconfig -a.

Comment: No I don't have it. How can I add it? And why doesn't it be added automatically with Vagrant when using public network?

Comment: As a workaround I would edit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-rename-wireless.rules and the following lines: SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0" where ATTR is the HWaddr from 'ifconfig -a' for your wifi. It appears this is a common concern raised with vagrant but I don't see a good solution.

Comment: When I access the rules.d directory and list its items I don't find the 70-rename-wireless.rules file. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I meant create that file and then restart the network interfaces.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/691107)

Comment: Still getting the same error :( here's what I wrote:

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{192.168.1.66}=="e4:ce:8f:15:fb:12", NAME="eth0"

Comment: @Pilot6 I have reworded my answer to fit that criteria. I am sorry, I didn't know that rule. Is this now acceptable?

Comment: It is OK now...